# magmi - Unable to update configurable product price for different websites using

Tags: magento, magmi

I used magmi to import simple and configurable products. I was also able to update the name and description of configurable products for different stores. But when I try to update product price, it doesnt work.

- I have 5 websites with 1 to 2 stores in each website
- The scope for `price` is set to global

The csv for updating the price is as follows

```
store,sku,price
"fr_fr,eu_fr,ch_fr,eu_de,ch_de,eu_en",421611test,170
"de_de,at_de,world_en,uk_en",421611test,180
```

- Magento version - 1.9.1
- Magmi - 0.7.21

This sets the price to 180 for all stores.  How should I fix this? I have googled as much as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the Magmi 0.7.21 version has a problem in updating price specific to the store. I used Magmi 0.7.20 with the same csv files and settings. It worked :)